# Optional support in Proto3 for Go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto, proto3

Does optional supports in proto3 while working with Go? I tried with this:

```sh
protoc person.proto --go_out=. --experimental_allow_proto3_optional
```

but got this error

> person.proto: is a proto3 file that contains optional fields, but code generator protoc-gen-go hasn't been updated to support optional
> fields in proto3. Please ask the owner of this code generator to
> support proto3 optional.--go_out:

**so proto3 (Go) does not support optional keyword?**

Answer (score 6):

`protoc` does support it, starting from version `v3.15.0`. See the [release notes](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.15.0):

> Optional fields for proto3 are enabled by default, and no longer require
> the `--experimental_allow_proto3_optional` flag.

The `protoc-gen-go` plugin does starting from `v1.22.0`. [Release notes](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/releases/tag/v1.22.0):

> This release adds support for the experimental proto3 optional semantics coming in the v3.12.0 release of the protobuf language, [...]

Make sure to upgrade your `protoc-gen-go` to version `v1.22.0` or above.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go#section-documentation
is this deprecated

Comment: @Khushi yes, the current library is https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go (module name `google.golang.org/protobuf`)

Comment: I am getting same issue(optional type) with https://github.com/nats-rpc/nrpc